# How can I add markup for hyphenation to taxonomy term titles?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm displaying a list of taxonomy terms in a narrow column. Some of the names are too wide to fit and wrap. I thought perhaps inserting a `<wbr>` in the name would solve this, but the tag is just printed out as a literal. Is there a way to use rich text in taxonomy term names?

Comment: mmm should avoid adding markup to names .. try to use css to fix your issue.

Comment: I agree adding markup in names is a bad idea. My real problem is that long names are breaking in arbitrary places, I would like them to break where hyphenation would occur, but I don't think there is a CSS solution for that. i.e, the word "subscriptions" would ideally break after "sub".  I thought adding a hint tag might work when used with `hyphens:manual`, I just wanted to experiment. I tried `word-break: break-word` which is for whole words. All I can think of now is either using some javascript to add the <wbr> tags, or (more realistically) tell the editors to just use shorter words.

Comment: Every HTML entity and every special symbol also has a unicode-counterpart, which can be entered as "single letter". On Windows PCs this usually is ALT + SOME_NUMBER. This is not just visual symbols like bullets or arrows, there is also a number for non-breaking space `&nbsp;` and there also is a number for soft-hyphen `&shy;`.

Comment: CSS hyphenation is very poor. Either go for `&shy;` or implement a hyphenation JS library.